# What is the fastest multi-human pose estimation model?

Tags: computer-vision, model-request, pose-estimation

I am trying to find an accurate and fast multi-person human pose estimation that I can train on with custom data. I have been searching for a little while and I may not be up-to-date on the newest techniques.  I will start by posting what I have found and looked into (a little):

1. [Openpose](https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose): This is supposedly real-time ([I assume on a GPU, 24fps?](https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose/issues/1547)) and they provide training code
2. [Lightweight OpenPose](https://github.com/Daniil-Osokin/lightweight-human-pose-estimation.pytorch): Runs in realtime >20fps confirmed, training code is provided
3. [mediapipe](https://github.com/google/mediapipe): runs in realtime > 20fps confirmed, [training code is NOT provided](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/2367)
4. [posenet](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/posenet): [No training code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/1581), can one even train tfjs models?
5. [movenet](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/movenet): Very fast but no way to train?
6. [hrnet & lightweight-hrnet](https://github.com/HRNet): seem to be slow? Can anyone confirm? training code provided
7. [blazepose](https://github.com/jiang-du/BlazePose-tensorflow): haven't tried it yet, looks like tf implementation, but no discussion bout speed. Training code included
8. [alphapose](https://github.com/MVIG-SJTU/AlphaPose): haven't tried it, but looks to run at 16fps (maybe faster?) but is only intended for research not commercial. Training script available.
9. [MoVnect](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.05097): Looks new, and fast (haven't tested it) but looks like it uses student-teacher training.

What are some other human poses estimation models out there?

I care more about speed and training. I am thinking #2 is my best bet but it's a few years old. And not the most friendly to train Anything newer? Can anyone confirm or reject my findings?

Comment: Hello. Could you please clarify this sentence "I care more about speed and training". What do you mean "I care about training"? Also, what do you mean by speed? Do you mean speed of inference (i.e. prediction) or maybe training time? Please, change the title after you have clarified this so that it's also clear what you mean by "speed". I changed the title to reflect more your current post's question/info, but this post is not fully clear to me, as it's not clear what your requirements really are.